# Do I add live load plus snow load to dead load?

Tags: foundation, engineering

I'm building a 10x16 shed/dry cabin and I am trying to figure out how much weight my footings need to support. Do I need to add live load + dead load + snow load?

- Live load is 30-50 psf based on codes
- Dead load - A cabin wood framed this size maybe weighs 2000 - 3000 pounds? (Based on pre built shed site spec sheets)
- Snow load in my area is 105 psf

50x160= 8000lbs + 2500lbs + 105x160= 16,800lb

Total 27,300 lbs

Divided by six footings is how much each needs to support?

Seems like overkill or I'm doing something very wrong.

Comment: The footings will need to support the MAXIMUM load which, logically, is the sum of all possible loads. Otherwise you get the issue where things like flood barriers are designed to withstand 50 year events then people are upset when 100 year events happen and they get wet.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I need to add live load + dead load + snow load?

Yes you do if you want to building to withstand those conditions.

> Divided by six footings is how much each needs to support?

You haven't provided the area of the roof but we can estimate with a flat roof which is 10x16 or 160 sq. ft.   The snow load is 105 lb/sq. ft. or 16,800 lb.  Supported by 6 piers that is 2800 lb. each.

> Seems like overkill or I'm doing something very wrong.

No, not overkill just engineering analysis.

Have you considered purchasing pre-designed building plans where an engineer or an architect has already done all this or hiring an engineer to do this work for you?  I'm not saying that this cannot be done by a non-engineer but it seems like you are skeptical about the process.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have considered but wanting to design and learn is also part of the process for me. I don't mean to sound skeptical, just wanting to be curious and learn.